# AX2009 - str data type limit

Tags: string, axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2009

Is there any limit on the size of the `str` data type in AX2009?

There is also the extended data type (Memo) which can be inherited by extended data types. What is the difference between a extended data type inherited by (Memo) and the `str` data type? As is not (Memo) also just a `str` data type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the limit: Yes and no.
For practical purposes it is unlimited but the X++ runtime has a certain limit which you can find out by feeding large values to the `strrep` function until you will encounter errors.

All EDTs based on strings are essentially 'mapped' to `str` in X++ but result in different column types in the database backend or different control properties when rendered in the UI.
So when considering X++, you can treat a `memo` EDT as the same as `str` but please notice that they come from different 'realms' of AX - `str` is the string type of X++ which is used for building up the business logic in AX and `memo` is the base EDT for unlimited strings when modelling the database and UI part of AX.

Answer (score 0):

The str datatype cannot contain more than roundabout 25.5 Million characters. You will get an error "Error executing code: Insufficient memory to run script." if you exceed that number.

At the moment I cannot think of any possible use scenario that will exhaust that length...