# AX2009 str type limited to 1000 characters

Tags: axapta, x++

I need to store a Xml buffer somewhere before processing it with `XmlDocument`. This can be done in a temporary file but I would prefer to work in memory.

I try to use a `str 10000` buffer, but I discovered that in my configuration, it is limited to 1000.

Example :

```
str 2000 strTest;
int i;

for (i=1; i<= 200; i++)
{
    strTest = strTest + "1234567890";
    info(strfmt("Length : %1", strlen(strTest)));
}
```

In the infolog I see that the Length remains stuck at the maximum value of 1000.

[Here is another question looking similar but I don't read a solution in it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39200235/ax2009-str-data-type-limit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discover that the example works if I replace `str 2000 strTest` by `str strTest`.

So the limit of 1000 applies only if we specify a size for the string, this can be seen only if the specified size is bigger than 1000.

This has the appearance of a small bug in AX.